# Laravel 5.4: Cannot retrieve data from a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, relationships

I'm trying to display the name of the assignee (foreign key from Users table) of each ticket by storing each name in an array from two UNION'd tables (Accesses and Reports) but it gives me this error.  ErrorException
Undefined property: stdClass::$assignee.

```
//HomeController
    $accesses = DB::table('accesses')
                ->select(array('id', 'fullname','emp_id','shift','state','resolved_at', 'closed_at','assigned_to'))
                ->where('state','=','Assigned');

    $all = DB::table('reports')
                ->select(array('id', 'fullname','emp_id','shift','state','resolved_at', 'closed_at','assigned_to'))
                ->union($accesses)
                ->where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
                ->get();

    $names[] = array();

    foreach ($all as $one)//store in array to display in a chart
    {
      $names[] = $one->assignee->name; //error here
    }




   //Report Model
   public function assignee()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to');
   }

   //Access Model
   public function assignee()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to');
   }

  //Report Migration
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('emp_id');
        $table->string('shift');
        $table->longText('report');
        $table->string('status')->default('Pending'); //Pending, Approved
        $table->string('state')->default('Open'); //Open, Assigned, Resolved, Closed
        $table->date('resolved_at')->nullable();
        $table->date('closed_at')->nullable();
        $table->integer('assigned_to')->nullable();
        $table->longText('action')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
   }

   //Access Migration
   public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('accesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('emp_id');
        $table->string('shift');
        $table->string('request');
        $table->longText('note')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->default('Pending'); //Pending, Approved
        $table->string('state')->default('Open'); //Open, Assigned, Resolved, Closed
        $table->date('resolved_at')->nullable();
        $table->date('closed_at')->nullable();
        $table->integer('assigned_to')->nullable();
        $table->longText('action')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
   }
```

[It gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLkg8.png)

[The results should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN0MW.png)

Comment: You're using the `DB` facade, rather than querying on a model. So you're not going to have access to any relationships.

Comment: do you just want the name of assignees? If so, why query all the fields? If not, add more information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `merge` method of collection:

```
$accesses = Access::select(array('id', 'fullname','emp_id','shift','state','resolved_at', 'closed_at','assigned_to'))
            ->where('state','=','Assigned')
            ->get();

$reports = Report::select(array('id', 'fullname','emp_id','shift','state','resolved_at', 'closed_at','assigned_to'))
            ->where('state', '=', 'Assigned')
            ->get();

$all = $accesses->merge($reports);
```

Comment: but if i use eloquent the union won't work because the tables don't have the same number of columns.

Comment: Updated my answer, it may be help you. @GrantGubatan

Comment: @GrantGubatan This won't work. Eloquent collections merge results based on the model primary key. If the same primary key exists in both results set, they're overwritten.